# SSH key across multiple machines with SSH chaining

Tags: ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I would like to be able to ssh across mutiple machines using the -A flag on ssh like:
ssh -A user@hostB ssh -A user@hostC

This works fine in scenarios where I have SSH keys allowing me to go from my machine (hostA) to hostB and then keys going from hostB to hostC. But what if I want to be able to go from A to C, but not allow key based communications from B to C? Is there a way that I can pass they key along the SSH pipe without actually storing and leaving that key on machine B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can pass they key along the SSH pipe without actually storing and leaving that key on machine B?

The key never leaves your local machine in the first place. The `-A` option only allows clients on hostB and hostC to submit *requests to sign data* back to your local ssh-agent. (SSH authentication works by using your keypair to make digital signatures.)

(Technically they can submit *any* ssh-agent command, including "list keys" or "add new key". However, there is no command to extract the private key or any other sensitive information.)

---

However, if hostB is completely untrusted (and you don't want it to have even the ability to submit authentication requests), use a different approach: run the 2nd client locally and forward the *SSH protocol* through the SSH "pipe". This way intermediate hosts will only see encrypted conversation.

The simplest method (in OpenSSH 7.3 and later) is the ProxyJump option:

```
ssh -J user@hostB user@hostC
```

Other choices are `-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user@hostB"` or static TCP tunnels via `-L`.